# Number of disc intersections using scala

Tags: scala

I'm new the world of scala.
I'm trying to solve a codility scala problem.
I first [implemented](https://codility.com/programmers/task/number_of_disc_intersections/) it on my machine and it gave no errors. 
however, on codility, it raises the error of

```
exec.scala:38: error: not found: value Solution
  val result: Int = Solution.solution ( A )
                    ^
one error found
```

I have no clue what that means even after a bit of googling.

Here is the solution I came up with in Scala

```
object NumberOfDiscIntersections {
    def solution(A: Array[Int]): Int = {
        var inter = 0 
        val sortedA = A.toList.sorted.toArray
        val length = sortedA.length
        var ind = 1
        var idx = 0
        while (idx <= length-1){
            ind = 0
            while (ind <= length-1) {
                var diff: Double = sortedA(ind) - sortedA(idx)
                if (diff > 0 ){ 
                    inter+=1
                }                
                ind += 1
            }
            idx +=1
        }
        inter
    }
    solution(Array(1,5,2,1,4,0))
}
```

Python implementation

```
 A = [1,5,2,1,4,0]
    sortedA = sorted(list(set(A)))
    length = len(sortedA)
    idx = 0
    inter = 1
    while(idx <= length - 1):
        ind = 0
        while(ind <= length -1):
            diff = sortedA[ind] - sortedA[idx]
            if (diff >0): inter+=1
            ind+=1
        idx+=1
    print inter
```

And it does in 11 solutions as expected.
Why does it raise an error? and is there a way to optimise it?

Comment: According to the error, it's looking for a `solution()` method inside a `Solution` object, but you put it in a `NumberOfDiscIntersections` object. Could that be the problem?

Comment: That fixed it. 
from what I see, I get 14 solutions instead of 11. However, in the Python implementation, I get exactly 11.

Comment: My bad, in line 4, it should be `A.toList.distinct.sorted.toArray`

could you please tell me if there is a way to optimise the solution

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve but from the code it looks like you want to compare every element in a set (a collection of distinct values) to all the other elements and count the number of times a > b.

I noticed that the Scala code comes up with a different result than the Python code because one initializes `inter` to 0 while the other initializes it to 1.

Since the max element is going to be greater than all the others, and the next-to-max will be greater than all-others-minus-one, etc., the result is going to be a [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  To optimize that I'd probably want to generate the triangle numbers lazily (i.e. only as needed) and then index to the desired result.

```
def solution(arr: Array[Int]): Int = {
  val tNumber:Stream[Int] = 0 #:: tNumber.zipWithIndex.map{case (n,x) => n+x}
  tNumber(arr.distinct.length)  // + 1 here if needed
}
```

Comment: I'm precisely trying to achieve this
https://codility.com/programmers/task/number_of_disc_intersections/

Comment: Ah, well in that case, before worrying about optimization you might start with an algorithm that produces the right result. Consider the input `Array(1,0,1,0,1)`. If I understand the problem correctly the result should be `6` (each `0` intersects with its left and right neighbor, and the center `1` intersects with the `1` on each side).